# how to fill textbox or paragraph using dropdown from api?

Tags: php

I have an API server and want to call the ID with a dropdown and when it is selected. The textbot also changes based on the contents of my API, which ID I choose.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Code</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
<?php foreach($data as $row) : ?>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" ><?= $row["Code"]; ?></a>                            
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
</div>                           
<p class="card-text"><?= $row["Desc"] ?></p>
<p class="card-text"><?= $row["LastUpdate"] ?></p>
</div>
```

help me pls

Comment: Hello @Victor, You can do that using AJAX, make a request to call your API on dropdown value changed and fill data to your textbox.

Comment: can u make some example? i dont know how to use ajax

Comment: I can solve issues or bugs if you have, not write a whole code for you. you have to try it your self first.

Comment: $('#dropDown').on('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        url : '***********,
        type : 'get',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : 'array',
        
        success: function (hasil) {
            console.log(hasil);
            
        }
    });
    
});

Comment: i try myself but it said script.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at

Comment: did you include jquery.js or jquery.min.js? if not include that first and check